# How to use OR and And operator in Custom condition in Devops Release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I'm working on a release pipeline there are many task one by one. Based on a specific task failed I have to execute a specific task to create bug.

I'm using custom condition under control option where my bug task will execute failed or succeedwithissue with status.
my condition is here:

```
or eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed'),eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'SucceededWithIssues')and (ne(variables['varName.ActivityId'], ''))
```

Here I want to achieve when my previous job is failed or succeedwithissue and  Activityid is not null/"" then only my bug creation task should run.

I'm getting syntax error can any one help me with.

Comment: thanks for your response. But this condition is not fulfilling my requirement My case is : job 1 job 2 job 3 job 4 Now when my only job 3 is failed then only my job 4 should execute. when job 1 or job 2 failed my job 3 and job 4 should skip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of syntax error your condition should be formatted like this:

```
and(or(eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed'),eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'SucceededWithIssues')),ne(variables['varName.ActivityId'], ''))
```

the sytnax is

```
and(subcondition1, subcondition2)
```

and not

```
subcodntion1 and subcondition2
```